# How to search records in database through textbox, and display it in the listview

Tags: vb.net

This is my search code, when I run it and try to search in the textbox. The listview becomes empty.

```
        Dim SqlQuery As String = "SELECT * FROM sample WHERE FirstName like ' % " & TextBox4.Text & " % ' "
        Dim SqlCommand As New OleDbCommand
        Dim SqlAdapter As New OleDbDataAdapter
        Dim TABLE As New DataTable
        'MsgBox("trigger")

        With SqlCommand
            .CommandText = SqlQuery
            .Connection = conn

        End With

        With SqlAdapter
            .SelectCommand = SqlCommand
            .Fill(TABLE)
        End With

        ListView1.Items.Clear()
        For i = 0 To TABLE.Rows.Count - 1
            With ListView1
                .Items.Add(TABLE.Rows(i)("ID"))
                With .Items(.Items.Count).SubItems
                    .Add(TABLE.Rows(i)("FirstName"))
                    .Add(TABLE.Rows(i)("MiddleName"))
                    .Add(TABLE.Rows(i)("LastName"))
                    .Add(TABLE.Rows(i)("Gender"))
                End With
            End With
        Next
    End Sub
```

Please help me. I really need it for my thesis and I'm a newbee in programming.

Comment: This is a really poorly presented question.  You don't give us any information with which to work.  So here's your homework:  1.  Figure out where in your code things start to go wrong (employ the use of breakpoints - google if you don't know how to use them).  2. Once you have that, think about what kinds of information YOU would need to solve this problem.  3.  Tell US that information.  4.  Remove the useless information you have provided already (first 2 code blocks).  5.  Read the FAQ for this site so you have a better understanding what is expected from questions and from answers.

Comment: As Dan-o said, "*trim the fat*". Not everything is necessary here; response will be greater if you do so.

Comment: i am very sorry sir :(

Comment: its in this code that im having error.. (sorry for the bad english. )    ListView1.Items.Clear()
        For i = 0 To TABLE.Rows.Count - 1
            With ListView1
                .Items.Add(TABLE.Rows(i)("ID"))
                With .Items(.Items.Count).SubItems
                    .Add(TABLE.Rows(i)("FirstName"))
                    .Add(TABLE.Rows(i)("MiddleName"))
                    .Add(TABLE.Rows(i)("LastName"))
                    .Add(TABLE.Rows(i)("Gender"))
                End With

            End With

        Next

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 Dim SqlQuery As String = "SELECT * FROM sample WHERE FirstName like ' % " & TextBox4.Text & " % ' "
        Dim SqlCommand As New OleDbCommand
        Dim SqlAdapter As New OleDbDataAdapter
        Dim TABLE As New DataTable
        'MsgBox("trigger")

        With SqlCommand
            .CommandText = SqlQuery
            .Connection = conn

        End With

        With SqlAdapter
            .SelectCommand = SqlCommand
            .Fill(TABLE)
        End With

        ListView1.Items.Clear()
        For i = 0 To TABLE.Rows.Count - 1
           Dim li As new ListViewItem
                li=ListView1.Items.Add(TABLE.Rows(i)("ID").ToString())
                li.SubItems.Add(TABLE.Rows(i)("FirstName").ToString())
                li.SubItems.Add(TABLE.Rows(i)("MiddleName").ToString())
                li.SubItems.Add(TABLE.Rows(i)("LastName").ToString())
                li.SubItems.Add(TABLE.Rows(i)("Gender").ToString())
        Next
```

Comment: sir it still doesnt work :( the listview is still turns  to empty when i search

Comment: sir where should i put it ? and what is a break point ?? i only start using vb last day.. :(( im a newbee in VB.. (sorry for the bad english )

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you didn't declare the I as Integer

```
Dim SqlQuery As String = "SELECT * FROM sample WHERE FirstName like ' % " & TextBox4.Text & " % ' "
        Dim SqlCommand As New OleDbCommand
        Dim SqlAdapter As New OleDbDataAdapter
        Dim TABLE As New DataTable
   ---->Dim I as Integer
        'MsgBox("trigger")

    With SqlCommand
        .CommandText = SqlQuery
        .Connection = conn

    End With

    With SqlAdapter
        .SelectCommand = SqlCommand
        .Fill(TABLE)
    End With

    ListView1.Items.Clear()
    For i = 0 To TABLE.Rows.Count - 1
       Dim li As new ListViewItem
            li=ListView1.Items.Add(TABLE.Rows(i)("ID").ToString())
            li.SubItems.Add(TABLE.Rows(i)("FirstName").ToString())
            li.SubItems.Add(TABLE.Rows(i)("MiddleName").ToString())
            li.SubItems.Add(TABLE.Rows(i)("LastName").ToString())
            li.SubItems.Add(TABLE.Rows(i)("Gender").ToString())
    Next
```